# Create tsv with percentages for every column bash

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I'm trying to create a new tsv from a tsv. In the first one I have a column with the sample names and several columns with numbers. In the second one I want to have the columns with the percentage of each column divided by the sum of all columns.

I have done this, which kind of works, but then it is not tab separated.
`cat multiqc_data/mqc_featurecounts_biotype_plot_1.txt | awk -v OFS='\t' -F'\t' 'NR>1{sum=0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i; NF++; $NF=sum } 1' | tail -n +2 | awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)$i/=$42}1' | rev | cut -d" " -f2- | rev`

Then, after, I tried to use `column -t -s " "` to transform it to tsv, but it didn't work, I don't know why.

Could you help me with this? If there is a different code that works I will be glad to try it. Thanks!

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help[ you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a new tsv from a tsv. In the first one I have a
> column with the sample names and several columns with numbers. In the
> second one I want to have the columns with the percentage of each
> column divided by the sum of all columns.

I would do it single GNU `AWK` call as follows, let `file.tsv` content be

```
A   10  10  10
B   10
C   10  20  30  40  50
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{t=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1){t+=$i};for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1){$i/=t};print}' file.tsv
```

gives output

```
A   0.333333    0.333333    0.333333
B   1
C   0.0666667   0.133333    0.2 0.266667    0.333333
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that tab character is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`). For each line I do set value of `t` to zero, then sum columns starting at 2nd, then divide each column starting at 2nd by sum, `print` all columns. Note that GNU `AWK` is not limited to standard input and can consume files without need of `cat`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: That would fail if all fields have value 0. Also, `i+=1` = `i++`.

Comment: In my case it is not a problem, since always some field will have value>0, but thanks for the warning.

Comment: You're welcome but assuming that is a classic recipe for disaster :-). It's also trivial to protect against so why not just do it, e.g. `$i=(t ? $i/t : 0)`, or `{t=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1){t+=$i}} t{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1){$i/=t};print}` or similar.